# R - write.table with variable/in-memory output?

Tags: r

I'd like to use `write.table` except that I want the "output" to be a variable in-memory and not a file on disk.  Basically I'm trying to get the string representation of a `data.frame` (with column aligned, no column headers).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this works.  any critiques?  I'm still ramping up on R.

```
PrettyPrintDataFrame = function( toPrint , separator = "" , align = "left" )
{        
    leftAlign = FALSE
    if ( align == "left" ) 
    {
        leftAlign = TRUE        
    }
    else if ( align == "right" )  {  }
    else
    {
        stop( "align must be 'left' or 'right'" )
    }

    result = ""
    numberOfColumns = ncol( toPrint )
    columnLenghts = array( dim = numberOfColumns )         
    for ( i in seq( 1:numberOfColumns ) )
    {
        columnLenghts[ i ] = max( nchar( toPrint[ , i ] ) )
    }

    numberOfRows = nrow( toPrint )    
    for ( row in seq( 1:numberOfRows ) )
    {   
        if ( row > 1 )
        {
            result = paste( result , "\n" , sep = "" )
        }

        for ( col in seq( 1:numberOfColumns ) )
        {
            value = toPrint[ row , col ]
            valuePadding = paste( rep( " " , columnLenghts[ col ]- nchar( value ) ) , collapse = "" , sep = "" )

            if ( leftAlign )
            {
                valuePadded = paste( value , valuePadding , sep = "" )
            }
            else
            {
                valuePadded = paste( valuePadding , value , sep = "" )
            }

            if ( col == 1 )
            {
                result = paste( result , valuePadded , sep = "" )
            }
            else            
            {
                result = paste( result , valuePadded , sep = separator )
            }

        }        
    }

    return( result )

}
```

test

```
df = data.frame( A = c( 500 , 12 , 8 ) , B = c( 1 , 13 , 938 ) , C = c( 92, 754 , 3 ) )
writeLines( PrettyPrintDataFrame( df , " | " ) )
```

Comment: You asked for some comments on your code. Here are some suggestions.  1) Using `=` for assign works, but `<-` is preferred.  2) You are using a double use of `seq` - `1:numberOfRows` is sufficient. 3) Your coding style is quite unlike typical R.  Here is a style guide I like, but there are others: http://had.co.nz/stat405/resources/r-style-guide.html 4) Use `ifelse` instead of `if{} else{}` - this is more compact.

Comment: @Andrie - thanks so much! I really appreciate this advice. Good catch on #2 and #4 (#4 I just discovered from the R Inferno doc which I'm halfway through...GREAT resource).  re:#1/#3  you are right...I take a number of departures from the Google style guidelines.

Answer (score 4):

Use `capture.output` to grab the output of `print`:

```
df.mem=capture.output(print(df, row.names=FALSE))
df.mem

[1] "   A   B   C" " 500   1  92" "  12  13 754" "   8 938   3"
```

Comment: thanks!  I don't think print always aligns columns properly, but its good to know that I can capture print().

Comment: @SFun28 You could capture `write.table` too: `capture.output(write.table(head(iris), header=FALSE))`.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of writing to a file, you can write to any connection.

I can do this:

```
x = matrix(rnorm(100), ncol = 10)

write.table(file = pipe("pbcopy"), x)
```

which writes the table to the clipboard.

I can then read it back in with

```
read.table(pipe("pbpaste"))
```

EDIT:

You can also round everything to a fixed number of digits then use a sep = "    " in the (write.table call) like this:

```
x = matrix(rnorm(100), ncol = 10)

write.table(file = pipe("pbcopy"), round(x, 2), sep = "    ")

readLines(pipe("pbpaste"))
```

results in

```
 [1] "      V1    V2    V3    V4    V5    V6    V7    V8    V9   V10"
 [2] "1  -0.73  0.10 -0.47  1.02 -0.13 -0.01 -1.00 -0.19 -1.10  0.29"
 [3] "2  -0.53 -0.29  0.60  1.41  2.09 -0.49 -2.48  0.17  0.88  1.53"
 [4] "3   1.16  0.28  0.40  0.36  0.16  0.03 -0.72  0.20  1.71 -1.10"
 [5] "4   0.63 -0.85 -0.23 -0.95  0.09  0.96  0.31 -0.05  1.07 -0.09"
 [6] "5  -1.15 -0.27  0.80  0.62 -0.77 -0.54  0.18 -0.16  0.27 -0.17"
 [7] "6   1.03 -2.19  1.54 -1.36  1.00  0.35 -0.84 -0.54 -0.33 -0.92"
 [8] "7   0.12  0.49 -2.03 -0.07  0.55  0.48  0.32  0.22 -0.44 -0.56"
 [9] "8  -0.13 -0.07 -0.28 -0.49  1.56 -2.00 -0.44 -0.04 -0.26  0.77"
[10] "9  -1.23 -0.53  0.57  0.08 -0.59  0.65 -0.15  0.44 -0.67  0.00"
[11] "10 -0.60  1.07 -1.82  0.39  1.11 -1.86  0.25  0.44  0.57  0.53"
```

Comment: @Greg - on the last line, I get the following error "Error in read.table(pipe("pbpaste")) : no lines available in input".  I'm on Windows, not sure if that matters.  Is this the system-wide clipboard?  Wouldn't other clipboard operations interfere with this?

Comment: Actually...I'm not sure now that write.table aligns columns.  It doesn't seem to

Comment: @SFun28 - I think `pipe("pbpaste")` may be OS X specific. Looking at `?pipe` under the "Clipboard" section, I don't see a method to do this on Windows. Are you trying to do some sort of pretty printing of a matrix? What could you do with a string representation of the matrix in memory?

Comment: @Greg - Correct, i'm trying to do pretty printing, except not to console - i'm  using the formatted text in a plot.  Is there a way to print() to a variable instead of console (w/column separator, and remove column names/ row names)?

Comment: You can use textConnection, too.

Comment: @SFun28 - so you are trying to print the contents of the matrix/data.frame onto the plot?

Comment: @Greg - I'm trying to format some text and print it to title are of a plot.  I might just build my own function for this formatting.

Comment: @Greg - posted a solution.  let me know what you think!